# Write an Umlaut (Unicode) to Bitmap

Tags: c++, opencv, unicode, bitmap

I have a program which should display some text on a screen, and it all works perfectly fine until I get to special (unicode) characters (in this case, München, the ü).

When I use OpenCV, it will just print a '?', and I don't know another feasible way on how to write text to a bitmap. I also tried Qt with addText in OpenCV, it adds some square instead.

Any idea how I can do that without too much trouble?

Edit: I want to use bitmaps or similar as I am generating a part of the image manually each frame, and use OpenCV for that, and its easy to embed a generated bitmap into that.

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV `putText` (don't know much about QT supported `addText`) function does not support unicode yet. If you're not too particular about the type of library to use, you can always install (or preferably build from source) the ImageMagick library. Then you can use the provided C++ API (Magick++).

```
#include <Magick++.h>

int main()
{
Magick::Image image;
image.read("image.bmp");
image.annotate("üüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüü", Magick::CenterGravity);
image.display();
}
```

Comment: The SVN of that site isn't working, and the libraries are Visual Studio 2013... any way around that?

Comment: @SinisterMJ Download page: https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ Build guide page: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

Comment: It does not work under VC 2013!!!! The last ImageMagick codes require full compatible with C++11 (VC2015 and later).